# Translation request for News re wpasupplicant during upgrade

Tags: wifi, security, wpa

During a routine upgrade (`sudo apt-get upgrade`), the following "news" appeared in my terminal window:

```
apt-listchanges: News
---------------------

wpasupplicant (2:2.6-19) unstable; urgency=medium

  With this release, wpasupplicant no longer respects the system
  default minimum TLS version, defaulting to TLSv1.0, not TLSv1.2. If
  you're sure you will never connect to EAP networks requiring anything less
  than 1.2, add this to your wpasupplicant configuration:

    tls_disable_tlsv1_0=1
    tls_disable_tlsv1_1=1

  wpasupplicant also defaults to a security level 1, instead of the system
  default 2. Should you need to change that, change this setting in your
  wpasupplicant configuration:

    openssl_ciphers=DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2

  Unlike wpasupplicant, hostapd still respects system defaults.

 -- Andrej Shadura <andrewsh@debian.org>  Sat, 15 Dec 2018 14:22:18 +0100
```

Could someone please translate this? And yes, I guess this is being a bit lazy, but as I read through this (several times), I feel it's not clearly worded.

Comment: This has to do with enterprise variants of WPA/WPA2 that uses a RADIUS server for authentication (using variants of the EAP protocol) - if you don't use WPA(2) Enterprise authentication, this should have zero effect on you

Answer (score 3):

If you have `apt-listchanges` installed, any `NEWS` file included in a new or upgraded package will be displayed.  That message detailed significant changes made in the maintainer's view.  Unless you are developing software or waiting for a bleeding edge change to be announced in the packaging, no action is required on your part normally.

Comment: It's installed, but don't recall that I've never installed it. And if it's a standard pkg installed by default, it strikes me as odd that this is the first notice I've seen in... quite a while as I began this when jessie was current. Appreciate the info, but it doesn't actually address my question.